# Nielsen-Ninomiya Theorem on a 2+1 lattice

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-chromodynamics, graphene

(a) In the paper on the proof of the Nielsen-Ninomiya [theorem](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321381905241), it is shown for 1+1 and 3+1 lattices. Does the proof hold on lattices with even number of spatial dimensions (e.g 2 spatial + 1 time)? If yes, what is the intuition behind the proof?

(b) Are there consequences of the theorem on condensed matter models for electrons in two dimensions, like graphene?

Comment: Chiral fermions don't exist in $2n+1$ dimensions because the equivalent $\gamma_5$ cannot be defined.

Comment: How do I understand that on a intuitive level?